# Word for conclusion arrived by ruling out all possible alternatives, however absurd this may seem?

Tags: single-word-requests

Word for conclusion arrived by ruling out all possible alternatives, however absurd the final conclusion may seem? This has links to philosophy-logical fallacies-arguements etc.

Comment: I think it is sometimes called "Holmes's dictum" or something along those lines, as it was stated by Sherlock Holmes in one of Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's storied.

Comment: The methodology is "reasoning by elimination". To complete @HotLicks comment, in the "sign of the Four", Sherlock Holmes says "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the conclusion is obviously absurd, the problem you are describing is what's known as a **Holmesian fallacy** (a.k.a. Sherlock Holmes fallacy or process of elimination fallacy):

> a logical fallacy that occurs when some explanation is believed to be true on the basis that **alternate explanations are impossible**, yet not all alternate explanations have been ruled out.

http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Holmesian_fallacy

I don't think there's a single word for a conclusion reached by means of this type of fallacious reasoning, but ["far-fetched hypothesis"](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Holmesian_fallacy#Far-fetched_hypothesis) or ["arcane explanation"](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Holmesian_fallacy#Alternate_names) might fit, depending on the context. Also "fallacious conclusion", but this applies to any fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

I would call this a [process of elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_of_elimination):

> a method to identify an entity of interest among several ones by excluding all other entities.

This is most often performed when taking multiple-choice tests. If you determine that choices A, B, and D cannot possibly be the correct answer, C must be the answer even if you're not sure why. You just know that you can't exclude it.